# Using Socket.io in android for Chat app

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to make a chat application for my college but my app is unable to communicate with my NodeJS Server hosted on heroku app.

1) The first activity of the app will take an username input from the user and send it to the server where I'll save it as a variable for the session.

2) After that the chat activity will open.

This is the code for the username input activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private EditText edit;
public String username;

private Socket mSocket;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nickedit);

    username = edit.getText().toString();

    {
        try {

            mSocket = IO.socket("https://backendchatio.herokuapp.com/");


        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            check();
           send();
        }
    });


}




public Boolean check() {

    if (edit.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;

    }

}


public void send() {

    if (check() != true) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    else {

        mSocket.emit("username",username);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Chatting.class);
        intent.putExtra("username", username);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

And this is the code of the NodeJS Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var listen = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req,res) {

console.log("Index");
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

console.log("A user has connected");

socket.on('disconnect', function() {

    console.log("A user has disconnected");
});

socket.on('username', function(username) {

    socket.username = username;
    console.log("A new user named" +username+ "Has joined");


});

socket.on('message',function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', function(username) {
        username: socket.username;
        message: data;
    });
})



});


http.listen(listen, function() {
    console.log("Server runnin at "+listen);
})
```

**The problem is that whenever I submit the username I expect it to log in my console (Heroku log) But It doesn't**

**I'm really new to android development and Websockets**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Some questions to diagnose the problem:

1) Does `heroku logs --tail` log `Server runnin at ...` ?

2) When you launch the app, does `heroku logs --tail` log `A user has connected` ?

3) Did your app launch properly/launch Chatting.class properly?

4) Does Android Monitor (Alt+6) print any error?